# Excel VBA HTML navigation (no id or class)

Tags: html, vba, excel

I've a VBA code that has to pull data from HTML. Part of the HTML is:

```
<td style="background-color: #8CBEF0">A</td>
```

There are several such instances of "td" in the HTML and I would need to scrape both the "background-color: #8CBEF0" and the value "A" in the above HTML.

The code I've tried with no success:

```
For Each ele In appIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("td")
If InStr(ele.Style, "background-color: #8CBEF0") > 0 
Then routerColor = ele.innerhtml: 
Exit For
Next
```

This code executes, but returns nothing. Does anyone have any ideas please?

Comment: Are you sure that `routerColor = ele.innerhtml` is actually executed ?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it?